# Network connection via wire and wifi

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router

I've encountered rather weird problem. I have a PC, a laptop and a router. PC is connected to router via wire. Laptop can be connected via both. The problem is, I can't see (nor ping it) laptop in the network from the PC if it's connected via wire, but everything works perfectly if it's connected via Wi-Fi. Internet works fine in both cases, but when laptop is connected via wire, they can't see each other, as if they're on different networks. Network discovery is on. Anyone knows what could be causing a problem?

`ipconfig /all output (PC)`

```
Windows IP Configuration

   Host Name . . . . . . . . . . . . : Komp
   Primary Dns Suffix .  . . . . . . :
   Node Type . . . . . . . . . . . . : Hybrid
   IP Routing Enabled. . . . . . . . : No
   WINS Proxy Enabled. . . . . . . . : No

Ethernet adapter Local Area Connection:

   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
   Description . . . . . . . . . . . : Intel(R) 82579V Gigabit Network Connection
   Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : {Omitted}
   DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : Yes
   Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes
   Link-local IPv6 Address . . . . . : fe80::9df1:bf86:c159:4b66%10(Preferred)
   IPv4 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.0.101(Preferred)
   Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.255.0
   Lease Obtained. . . . . . . . . . : 27 вересня 2016 р. 21:48:30
   Lease Expires . . . . . . . . . . : 4 листопада 2152 р. 4:56:45
   Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.0.1
   DHCP Server . . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.0.1
   DHCPv6 IAID . . . . . . . . . . . : 393531435
   DHCPv6 Client DUID. . . . . . . . : {Omitted}

   DNS Servers . . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.0.1
   NetBIOS over Tcpip. . . . . . . . : Enabled
```

`ipconfig /all output (Laptop)`

```
Windows IP Configuration

   Host Name . . . . . . . . . . . . : Lappy
   Primary Dns Suffix  . . . . . . . :
   Node Type . . . . . . . . . . . . : Hybrid
   IP Routing Enabled. . . . . . . . : No
   WINS Proxy Enabled. . . . . . . . : No

Wireless LAN adapter Wireless Network Connection:

   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
   Description . . . . . . . . . . . : Realtek RTL8723BE Wireless LAN 802.11n PC I-E NIC
   Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : {Omitted}
   DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : Yes
   Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes
   Link-local IPv6 Address . . . . . : fe80::ccf6:b4b:d62a:8542%14(Preferred)
   IPv4 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.0.104(Preferred)
   Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.255.0
   Lease Obtained. . . . . . . . . . : 27 вересня 2016 р. 22:03:19
   Lease Expires . . . . . . . . . . : 4 листопада 2152 р. 4:54:45
   Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.0.1
   DHCP Server . . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.0.1
   DHCPv6 IAID . . . . . . . . . . . : 347637383
   DHCPv6 Client DUID. . . . . . . . : {Omitted}

   DNS Servers . . . . . . . . . . . : 8.8.8.8
                                       8.8.4.4
   NetBIOS over Tcpip. . . . . . . . : Enabled

Ethernet adapter Local Area Connection:

   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
   Description . . . . . . . . . . . : Realtek PCIe FE Family Controller
   Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : {Omitted}
   DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : Yes
   Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes
   Link-local IPv6 Address . . . . . : fe80::7927:fe52:4d52:b76e%13(Preferred)
   IPv4 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.0.103(Preferred)
   Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.255.0
   Lease Obtained. . . . . . . . . . : 27 вересня 2016 р. 21:39:10
   Lease Expires . . . . . . . . . . : 4 листопада 2152 р. 4:54:45
   Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.0.1
   DHCP Server . . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.0.1
   DHCPv6 IAID . . . . . . . . . . . : 301478628
   DHCPv6 Client DUID. . . . . . . . : {Omitted}

   DNS Servers . . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.0.1
   NetBIOS over Tcpip. . . . . . . . : Enabled
```

Comment: Please [edit] the question and add the output from running `ipconfig /all` in a `cmd` prompt for the PC and for the laptop with a wired connection.

Comment: My first thought would be the network type and / or domain.
On the laptop is the wired network a home network? Does it have a firewall on?
Are they in the same workgroup? i would check the IP and gateway of both machines and see if maybe your router is assigning them to different zones.

Comment: Same work group, no domains used, same gateway. Both connections on the laptop are home networks.

Comment: @DavidPostill done

Comment: Can you ping the other way? Laptop to PC.

Comment: Can you disable the wireless on the Laptop and see if that fixes it?

Comment: What OS are you using on each machine?

Comment: @DavidPostill Both have Win 7, though with varying architecture and editions, but that shouldn't matter. Disabling doesn't help. And I can't ping either way because it gives host unreachable

Comment: Can you disable wifi when working with cable and ensure if it then works? It may be that the wifi is not disabled when the wired connection is being used.

Comment: @LPChip It does not. That's how I've been trying to begin with

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried disabling the wireless network on your laptop before pinging the router? It looks like you have both wired and wireless interfaces active, on the same subnet - this may confuse Windows.

Also, I notice that your DNS IP for the wireless interface is 8.8.8.8 & 8.8.4.4 whereas on the wired interface you are using the router's address. This implies that you have manually configured the wireless interfaces (at least partially). This won't affect pinging by IP, but did you try to ping by name as Google's DNS won't know about your 'lappy' machine. Name resolution could work via Netbios though as this is enabled.

Another thing to check is that you don't have a faulty cable - you could confirm the cable works between the router and PC.

Comment: Yes, I tried that. Also tried 3 different cables in all ports of the router. DNS can't possibly matter in this case.